# What do each of the keys in the $_schema var in models do in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, model, schema

The CakePHP cookbook presents the following (http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#schema):

> Contains metadata describing the model’s database table fields. Each field is described by:
>
> - name
> - type (integer, string, datetime, etc.)
> - null
> - default value
> - length

Some of these are self-explanatory, but here are my questions:

1. Name - what's the purpose of this?  Is the cakebook just unclearly saying that the other values will be in an array stored under the name of the field, or is this a key that can give a different name, and what would it be for?
2. Type - I understand what type is, but could someone give me a full list of the options?  Hard to say what it is if I don't know what my options are.  Are they based on typical database types, or form types, or what?
3. Null - Is this the same as the not null option of a database?  Basically just requiring a value or throwing an error?

I would like to write out each of my table's schemas for various reasons, but I'm a little stuck because of these questions.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can find most of the answers to your questions yourself.
either you debug the returned data from

```
$this->Model->schema();
```

which contains all the fields above.
Or you use the cake shell to create/dump a schema file in /Config/Schema:

```
cake schema generate
```

this way you can look at what cake creates.

So if you create a dummy table "foobars" with all kind of field types you will have a full schema reference out of the box for the current cake version you are using. Also you will see your database reflected as cake sees it. meaning: if you set one field to "default not null", the other as "default null" you will see what "null" means. And what type of the database matches what type in cake.

And yes, name is the fieldname. it should be the array key itself, though.

Comment: for more infos and some examples see http://www.dereuromark.de/2012/05/01/schema-reference-for-table-less-models/